# Obtener valores de un array en PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html

Tengo un archivo `JSON` metido dentro de un `Array`, en el cual obtengo los valores mediante `PHP`:

```
// Esto es el Array
[
  {
    "title": "2.0 A",
    "T_label": "Tarifa",
    "P_label": "POWER",
    "power": {
      "0": {
        "type": "Pruebas",
        "value": "Pruebas"
      }
    },
    "E_label": "ENERGY",
    "energy": {
      "0": {
        "type": "Pruebas",
        "value": "Pruebas"
      }
    },
    "btn": {}
  }
]


// Con una función, obtengo los datos de ese `Array` y lo codifico como JSON

public function _display(){
        $this->media();

        $cjon = json_decode($this->val("json"));
if(!$cjon ){
    $cjon=[];
}

// Imprimo los datos del JSON

$title = "";
        foreach ($cjon as $key => $value) {
            print_rp($value->title);

            foreach ($value->power as $key1 => $value1) {
                print_rp($value1->type);
                print_rp($value1->value);
            }

            foreach ($value->energy as $key2 => $value2) {
                print_rp($value2->type);
                print_rp($value2->value);
            }
        }

echo $title;
// Esto imprime correctamente el título


// El problema viene aquí, a la hora de insertar los valores de dicho `JSON`
//dentro de la estructura de `divs` en el `return`
        
        return '<div class="mod-tarifa-des">
                    <div class="mod-tarifa-des-header">


// Aqui intento poner el valor del título
                        <p class="mod-tarifa-des-title">$title</p>
// Aqui intento poner el valor del título


                        <span class="mod-svg">
                            <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M7.41 8.59L12 13.17l4.59-4.58L18 10l-6 6-6-6 1.41-1.41z"></path></svg>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mod-tarifa-des-body">
                        <div class="mod-tarifa-des-block">
                            <p class="mod-tarifa-des-block-title">Precios por potencia (€/kW día)</p>
                            <div class="mod-tarifa-prices">
                                <span class="mod-tarifa-p1">P1 | </span><span class="mod-tarifa-now">0,135465 </span><span class="mod-tarifa-tag">€/kW día</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mod-tarifa-des-block">
                            <p class="mod-tarifa-des-block-title">Precios energía (€/kW día)</p>
                            <div class="mod-tarifa-prices">
                                <span class="mod-tarifa-p1">P1 | </span><span class="mod-tarifa-now">0,168448 </span><span class="mod-tarifa-tag">€/kW día</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mod-tarifa-prices">
                                <span class="mod-tarifa-p1">P3 | </span><span class="mod-tarifa-now">0,097818 </span><span class="mod-tarifa-tag">€/kW día</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mod-tarifa-des-bts">
                            <a href="https://www.www.localhost/LOGOS/coleccion-2020" class="mod-tarifa-cond">Ver condiciones</a>
                            <a href="?type_local=1&amp;type_supply=1&amp;key=set-step-2" class="mod-tarifa-calc-bt">Calcula tu ahorro</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>';
    }
```

Intento insertarlo como buenamente puedo, pero no me sale.
¿Hay alguna forma de insertar valores dentro del `return`?

Comment: ¿Quieres leer el array que muestras al principio de la pregunta? Me parece que lo esencial del problema se pierde entre tantas explicaciones que no vienen al caso para resolver el problema. Sin embargo, cosas fundamentales no son explicadas. Por ejemplo, ¿de qué forma quieres mostrar los datos (hay varias formas de leer un array, puedes querer mostrar sólo los valores o las claves y los valores)? Otra cosa es que los JSON que contiene el array no son iguales, debes explicar o mostrar qué estructura tienen los elementos que hay dentro del array, pues si son todos irregulares se complica.

Comment: Vale, como he avanzado un poco en el proyecto, tengo algo mucho más claro que preguntar, ahora edito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la forma de concatenar los valores!

```
    public function _display(){
        $this->media();

        $cjon = json_decode($this->val("json"));
if(!$cjon ){
    $cjon=[];
}

    $title      = "";

    $T_label    = "";
    $P_label    = "";
    $E_label    = "";

    $p_type     = "";
    $p_value    = "";

    $e_type     = "";
    $e_value    = "";
        foreach ($cjon as $key => $value) {
            $title .= $value->title;
            $T_label .=$value->T_label;
            $T_label .=$value->P_label;
            $T_label .=$value->E_label;

            foreach ($value->power as $key1 => $value1) {
                $p_type .= $value1->type;
                $p_value .= $value1->value;
            }

            foreach ($value->energy as $key2 => $value2) {
                $e_type .= $value2->type;
                $e_value .= $value2->value;
            }
        }

        echo $title;
        echo $T_label;
        echo $P_label;
        echo $E_label;
        echo $p_type;
        echo $p_value;
        echo $e_type;
        echo $e_value;

        //return $cjon = $this->val("json");
        
        return '<div class="mod-tarifa-des">
                    <div class="mod-tarifa-des-header">
                        <p class="mod-tarifa-des-title">'. $title .'</p>
                        <span class="mod-svg">
                            <svg preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M7.41 8.59L12 13.17l4.59-4.58L18 10l-6 6-6-6 1.41-1.41z"></path></svg>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mod-tarifa-des-body">
                        <div class="mod-tarifa-des-block">
                            <p class="mod-tarifa-des-block-title">'. $P_label .'</p>
                            <div class="mod-tarifa-prices">
                                <span class="mod-tarifa-p1">'. $p_type .' | </span><span class="mod-tarifa-now">'. $p_value .' </span><span class="mod-tarifa-tag">€/kW día</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mod-tarifa-des-block">
                            <p class="mod-tarifa-des-block-title">Precios energía (€/kW día)</p>
                            <div class="mod-tarifa-prices">
                                <span class="mod-tarifa-p1">'. $e_type .' | </span><span class="mod-tarifa-now">'. $e_value .'</span><span class="mod-tarifa-tag">€/kW día</span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="mod-tarifa-prices">
                                <span class="mod-tarifa-p1">'. $e_type .' | </span><span class="mod-tarifa-now">'. $e_value .' </span><span class="mod-tarifa-tag">€/kW día</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mod-tarifa-des-bts">
                            <a href="https://www.www.localhost/LOGOS/coleccion-2020" class="mod-tarifa-cond">Ver condiciones</a>
                            <a href="?type_local=1&amp;type_supply=1&amp;key=set-step-2" class="mod-tarifa-calc-bt">Calcula tu ahorro</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>';
    }
```

Todo es con el   código'. variable .'código